# how to compare keyword inside xml node in c#

Tags: asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

i having created a page of asp.net which is reading xml file node for some text.
below is how my xml file looks like.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Questions>
  <Question id="1">What is IL code </Question>
  <Answer1>Half compiled,Partially compiled code </Answer1>
  <Question id="2">What is TL code </Question>
  <Answer2>Half compiled,Partially compiled code </Answer2>
</Questions>
```

i have also created a .aspx page which has a label for displaying question and a text where user can enter his/her answer for that particular question and below one button has some code like below

```
    XmlDocument docQuestionList = new XmlDocument();// Set up the XmlDocument //
    docQuestionList.Load(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\questioon\questioon\QuestionAnswer.xml"); //Load the data from the file into the XmlDocument //
    XmlNodeList AnswerList = docQuestionList.SelectNodes("Questions/Question");
    foreach (XmlNode Answer in AnswerList)
    {
        if (Answer.InnerText.Trim() == lblQuestion.Text)
        {
            if (Answer.NextSibling.InnerText.Trim() == txtUserAnswer.Text)
            {
                // This is right Answer
                TextBox1.Text = "right";
            }
            else
            {
                // This is wrong Answer
                TextBox1.Text = "wrong";
            }
        }
    }
```

i want to display percentage for the answer enterd by the user for a particular question.

for example suppose question is ....What is IL code? and the user enters answer as Partially compile..so i want to only check the entered kweyword inside my xml answer node.

if the user answer is matched with node answer then display the accuracy of answer in percentage.

please help...

thanks,

Comment: Does your XML file *have* to have that format? It would be much more sensible to have an element per question, with the answer *inside* that element, rather than alternating between questions and answers. It's not relevant to the question particularly (none of the XML part is - you're really just interested in string similarity) but it'll make your life easier.

Comment: To add to Jon's comment - it seems especially bad to have different element types for each answer (as opposed to the questions, which all use the same element type)

Comment: can you suggest an example so that i can make use of it....and thanks for yours precious comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, all answers element should have same tag.

If it is not a restriction to use [XLinq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299195) and The answer tag is in format AnswerXXX then following code is for determining questions, answers and percantage of answers (total questions/ total answers), and percantage of correct answers (correct answers / total answers).

You can customize comparision logic as per your exact need.

```
        var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
        "<Questions>" +
        "<Question id=\"1\">What is IL code </Question>" +
        "<Answer1>Half compiled,Partially compiled code </Answer1>"+
        "<Question id=\"2\">What is TL code </Question>"+
        "<Answer2>Half compiled,Partially compiled code1 </Answer2>"+
        "</Questions>";

        var correctAnswerText1 = "Half compiled,Partially compiled code ";// set it to txtUserAnswer.Text


        XElement root= XElement.Parse(xml); // Load String to XElement
        var questions = root.Elements("Question"); // All questions tag
        var answers = root.Elements().Where(e=> e.Name.LocalName.Contains("Answer")); //All answers tag
        var correctAnswers = answers.Where( e=> !e.IsEmpty && String.Equals(e.Value, correctAnswerText1)); // All correct answers, here answer comparision logic can be customized

        var answerPercent = questions.Count()*100/answers.Count();
        var correctAnswerPercent = questions.Count()*100/answers.Count();
        questions.Dump();
        answers.Dump();
        correctAnswers.Dump();
        percantage.Dump();
        //root.Dump();
```